# How to change foreach in php?

Tags: php, foreach

I have some code that I edited, and the `foreach` loop is echoing out the value twice.  I know WHY, but I don't know how to convert one of the `foreach` to just be a variable?  Or string?

```
foreach( $attendee_datas[$EM_Ticket_Booking->ticket_id] as $attendee_title => $attendee_data ){
    $attendees = $EM_Booking->booking_meta['attendees']; 
    foreach($attendees as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $value_attendee) {
            echo $value_attendee["attendee_fname"]." ".$value_attendee["attendee_lname"] . "\r\n";
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For starters, `$value = $value_attendee` should be flipped. You are currently overwriting `$value` with the contents of `$value_attendee` when I'm sure you mean to do the opposite.

Comment: Where is `$value_attendee` being defined?

Comment: @RobW, I think the OP is trying to echo each of the values, but flip-flopped the assignment call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the edited code:

```
foreach( $attendee_datas[$EM_Ticket_Booking->ticket_id] as $attendee_title => $attendee_data ){
$attendees = $EM_Booking->booking_meta['attendees'];
$attendee_count = 0; 
foreach($attendees as $value) {
    foreach($value as $value_attendee) {
        $attendee_info[$attendee_count] = $value_attendee["attendee_fname"]." ".$value_attendee["attendee_lname"] . "\r\n";
    }
     ++$attendee_count;
    }
foreach($attendee_info as $attending)
{
  echo $attending;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  No names come through :-(

Comment: I do almost have it with this code, it's just repeating each name twice for each ticket type.  (this line states the ticket type `echo "\r\n". __('<strong>','em-pro'). $EM_Ticket_Booking->get_ticket()->ticket_name ."</strong>\r\n". '';`)
http://pastebin.com/MZ5Lkyq7

Comment: The whole page or just the section that is supposed to be producing the output?  The code I wrote is valid. I took out the $key variable, though, since we aren't using it.

Comment: Here's a the array functionality based on your pastebin - http://pastebin.com/TZQHx7p1

Comment: Thank you.  That almost worked!  I just have to stare at it a little more.  There are 2 ticket types.  Member and test.  The output had the same name for both types (It should be a different name for each type).

http://screencast.com/t/MRtkoHSxVm

Comment: Look at $value_attendee. I'm assuming that it has more than just attendee_fname and attendee_lname. I'm thinking it should have a ticket category designation that would allow you to create an if then statement that would compare it with  $EM_Ticket_Booking->get_ticket()->ticket_name (or id related to that name) and if they are equal then it will populate the array.

Comment: I will check that out.  Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.  I will do more investigating!

Answer (score 0):

Does $attendee_datas[$EM_Ticket_Booking->ticket_id] and $EM_Booking->booking_meta['attendees'] give you the same data? If it does then I would re-write it like this:

```
$EM_Tickets_Bookings = $EM_Booking->get_tickets_bookings();
$attendee_datas = EM_Attendees_Form::get_booking_attendees($EM_Booking);
foreach( $EM_Tickets_Bookings->tickets_bookings as $EM_Ticket_Booking ){
//Display ticket info
if( !empty($attendee_datas[$EM_Ticket_Booking->ticket_id]) ){
echo "\r\n". __('<strong>','em-pro').     $EM_Ticket_Booking->get_ticket()->ticket_name ."</strong>\r\n". '';
//display a row for each space booked on this ticket
foreach( $attendee_datas[$EM_Ticket_Booking->ticket_id] as $attendee_title => $attendee_data ){
        echo $attendee_data["attendee_fname"]." ".$attendee_data["attendee_lname"] . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No.. those are pulled from different areas.  EM_Ticket_Booking->ticket_id gets the ticket id from someone that booked the event, and the $EM_Booking->booking_meta['attendees'] is from the actual people attending (2 different forms)

Comment: Ah okay. I see you changed your code. Let me work with the new one.